# How do I parse a Promise JS Object to a singluar variable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json

I write Python 99% of the time but decided to start playing with [Amazon Cloudscape](https://cloudscape.design) and therefore started to write some React. It's been a slog...

I have a backend service (flask) that returns a JSON object of data I want to use in order to create a line-chart (using the [Cloudscape Linechart component](https://cloudscape.design/components/line-chart/?tabId=playground)). However, the JSON data is within a promise (Async fetch statements) and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to assign it to a variable that can be used as an export for my Linechart component class.

How do I:

1. Get rid of the Promise object (parse it)
2. Get a valid array in its own variable
3. Be able to consume the variable (export) in a different class (e.g., `import {my_var} from "./my_class"`).

I need to do some math on this data which complicates this.

**Fetch Function that returns a Promise**

```js
export async function GetRegionRidecounts(region) {
   try {
      var response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/get_region_ridecounts?region_name=' + region, {
         method: 'GET',
         mode: 'cors',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
      });
      return await response.json()
   } catch (error) {
      return { "error": error };
   }
}
```

**Consumer function that returns a Linechart**

```js
export default function RidersLineChart(region) {
    console.log(region)
    GetRegionRidecounts("west-lake-marion-park")
    .then(data => {
    return <LineChart
        height={200}
        series={data}
        xDomain={[data[0].date,data[data.length -1].data]}
        yDomain={[0, 500]}
        xScaleType="time"
        xTitle="Time (UTC)"
        yTitle="Data transferred"
        ariaLabel="Network traffic"
        ariaDescription={`Line chart showing transferred data of all your instances.`}
    />
    });
}
```

Edit 1: I've tried to use the `useState` capabilities but get the following errors:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

**Example Function that throws error**

```js
export async function GetRegionRidecounts(region) {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
   try {
      await fetch('http://localhost:5000/get_region_ridecounts?region_name=' + region, {
         method: 'GET',
         mode: 'cors',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
      }).then(response => {return response.json()})
      .then(data => {setData(data)});
      console.log(data)
      return data
   } catch (error) {
      return { "error": error };
   }
}
```

Comment: Set the data to state, and once the state has been populated, return the component

Comment: I've attempted to do that with:

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

But get an error: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: Either make `GetRegionRidecounts` a custom hook, or move all the logic to your component